# Tabular email format along with attachment

Tags: sendmail, html

I have a customer file which is generated at a path. I want to send the data in that file in tabular format along with  the file as attachment in the email.
I had a sample script from which i took help below is what i got:

```
  #initialising variables
dt=`date +%Y%m%d`;
FROM=Fraser@dmart.com
TO="shannon.zone@dmart.com";
CC=""
BCC=""
SUBJECT="Manager Accounts KPI Results - $dt";
BOUNDARY="PARAEND";
set -x
File_path="/File_gen/data"
script_path="/File_gen/data"
Mail_Content="$File_path/Customer_KPI_Mail.ml"

Mail_Opener()
{
echo "From: "$FROM"
To: "$TO"
cc: "$CC"
bcc: "$BCC"
Subject: "$SUBJECT"
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$BOUNDARY\"

--$BOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/html
<html>
<style>
table{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
caption{
margin:0;
padding:0;
#border:1px solid black;
}

th{
 background-color:#BAFFBA;
}
</style>
<body>
<span id='notification'> <i> << This is an automated notification. please do not respond to this email.>> </i> </span> <br /> <br />

<div>
Hi All - <br /> <br />
Please find the results $dt .<br /> <br />

<table border=1 cellpadding=3>
<tr>
 <th> Rule_Name </th>
 <th> Lower_Variance </th>
 <th> Upper_Variance </th>
 <th> Current_Day_Variance </th>
 <th> Result_Check </th>

</tr>

" > $Mail_Content
}


Mail_Closure()
{
echo "</table><br /> <br />
</div>
<div>Thanks, <br />
Global Team </div>
</body>
</html>" >> $Mail_Content
}


Table_Content_Designer()
{
 col1="$1";
 col2="$2";
 col3="$3";
 col4="$4";
 col5="$5";

  echo "<td> $col1 </td>" >> $Mail_Content
  echo "<td> $col2 </td>" >> $Mail_Content
  echo "<td> $col3 </td>" >> $Mail_Content
  echo "<td> $col4 </td>" >> $Mail_Content
  echo "<td> $col5 </td>" >> $Mail_Content

}

Mail_Opener;

cat "$script_path/cust_acct_check.txt" |sed 1d | while read line
do
        line="$File_path"/"$line";
                counter=1;
        line_count=`wc -l $line | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`;

        cat $line | while read data
        do
                col1=`echo $data | awk -F "," '{print $1}'`;
        col2=`echo $data | awk -F "," '{print $2}'`;
        col3=`echo $data | awk -F "," '{print $3}'`;
        col4=`echo $data | awk -F "," '{print $4}'`;
        col5=`echo $data | awk -F "," '{print $5}'`;


                if [ $counter -gt 1 ]; then
                if [ $counter -eq $line_count ];then
                        Table_Content_Designer "$col1" "$col2" "$col3" "$col4" "$col5";
                        echo "</tr>"  >> $Mail_Content
                        counter=`expr $counter + 1`;
                fi
                if [ $counter -lt $line_count ];then
                        Table_Content_Designer "$col1" "$col2" "$col3" "$col4" "$col5";
                        echo "</tr>"  >> $Mail_Content
                        echo "<tr>" >> $Mail_Content
                        counter=`expr $counter + 1`;
                fi
        else
                counter=`expr $counter + 1`;
        fi
        done
done
Threshold_File="$File_path/cust_acct_check.txt"

if [ -s "$Threshold_File" ];then
        echo "</table><br /> <br />
</div>
<div>The data file is alos located at Target path  <br />
 Please reach out to the GDMART <GDMART@dmart.com> in case of any questions.   <br /> <br /></div>
<div>Thanks, <br />
Global Team </div>
</body>
</html>

--$BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application;name="cust_acct_check.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base32
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cust_acct_check.txt"
" >> $Mail_Content
cat "$Threshold_File" >> $Mail_Content
else
 Mail_Closure;
fi
cat "$Mail_Content" | sendmail -t
```

Below is the csv file which i want to put in table format:

```
#key_rule,Lower_variance,Upper_variance,Actual_value,Result_check
MGR_ACCT_CNT,0,9000,8,True
MGR_BAL_CHK,-0.035,0.035,0.063997,False
MGR_ACCT_COM,-1,1,1.170281,False
```

I am not able to get the data in the table generate only getting the headers.
[image]

Comment: if you use the code that generates the table as a standalone and direct the output to a file is it generated as you'd expect?

Comment: Hi Banjosa, I tried the same but I am not sure why to put the code for the table html part in the script